# How to stop iOS downsampling images when sharing via email?

Tags: ipad, email, photos, screen-capture, ipados

Whenever I share a screenshot via email or other means, the photo is always downsampled to a very low resolution automatically. I can't figure out how to disable this - I want to share screenshots as they are, or at least be asked what size/resolution they should be downsampled to before sending. Can anyone suggest what settings to change?

I have an iPad (running iPad iOS 15.6.1) with iCloud Photos **disabled**; this issue does **not** seem to relate to iCloud.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing your photos in the photos app and using the share control from that or using mail to browse the files?

Comment: Neither. My usual pattern is take screengrab, sometimes add highlights (and sometimes not), then share the image from within the screengrab, and choose Mail as the sharing method.

Comment: When I do this it always asks me if I would like to downsample, and does nothing if I choose to use the original file size

Comment: @Ezekiel, I get that "correct/good" behavior on another device (old iPhone SE running iOS 14.8.1), but not on my newer iPad, and can't figure out what makes them different...